# Boost graph bundled properties with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, unique-ptr, boost-graph

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932641/5587903) shows a `std::unique_ptr` as a member of a bundled property with boost-graph.

The provided example can be tried out
**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f1777df46c375d)</kbd>**.

As I am only interested in the design aspect and not the algorithmic part of that answer, I provide a simplified example **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad63c2633e9d9b92)</kbd>**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct custom_node{
    custom_node(std::string name, int capacity) : name(name), capacity(capacity) {}
    
    std::string name = "uninitialized";
    int capacity = -1;
};
void usage(){}

using namespace boost;

struct VertexProperties {
    int id;
    std::unique_ptr<custom_node> node;
};

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, VertexProperties> DirectedGraph;
typedef graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::vertex_descriptor custom_vertex;
typedef graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::edge_descriptor custom_edge;

int main() {
    DirectedGraph g;

    boost::add_vertex(g);    
    g[0].node = std::make_unique<custom_node>("inner", 2);
    
    ////boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties{0, std::make_unique<custom_node>("inner", 2)}, g); // compilation error
    
    std::cout << boost::num_vertices(g);
    std::cout << g[0].id << "\n";
    std::cout << g[0].node->name << "\n";
    std::cout << g[0].node->capacity << "\n";
}
```

The vertex can be added via `boost::add_vertex(g)` and then the `std::unique_ptr` can be instantiated.

If I try to to achieve the same thing by creating the vertex with all properties via list initialization in `add_vertex`, there is a compilation error about the `implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'VertexProperties'`.
`VertexProperties`, of course, has its copy constructor deleted, because `std::unique_ptr` has its copy constructor deleted.

Why is the copy constructor even necessary for list initialization in the first place? Is there something I do not understand about it, or is this a shortcoming of boost-graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the copy constructor is necessary for list initialization in the first place? Is there something I do not understand about it, or is this a shortcoming of boost-graph?

That's not a thing and also not what's happening.

> Aside: in copy-initialization the assignment can be elided by the compiler, but operator= still *needs to be accessible* for it to be valid code.

But in this case it's just about the library code not being move-aware. You have to realize that "bundled" properties are separately stored. The bundle (as any property) is required to be default constructible anyways (so `add_vertex(g)` works) so the implementation is simplified by always assigning to the default-constructed property.

Since it's not move-aware, assignment will not forward the rvalue and things don't compile.

## OPTIONS

0. The linked answer already showd:

   ```
   if(g[v].node_logic) {
       g[v].node.reset(new custom_node(g[v].vertex_name, 0, standby, normal));
   }
   ```
1. More options:

   ```
   VertexProperties props {0,
       std::make_unique<custom_node>("inner", 2)};
   auto vd = boost::add_vertex(g);
   g[vd] = std::move(props);
   ```
2. Wrap yo' shit! You can create any interface you prefer:

   ```
   auto add_vertex = [&g](VertexProperties&& props) {
       auto vd = boost::add_vertex(g);
       g[vd] = std::move(props);
       return vd;
   };

   add_vertex({0, std::make_unique<custom_node>("inner", 2)});
   ```
3. You can even elaborate on that:

   ```
   auto add_vertex = [&g](int id, std::string name, int capacity = -1) {
       auto vd = boost::add_vertex(g);
       g[vd] = { id, std::make_unique<custom_node>(name, capacity) };
       return vd;
   };

   add_vertex(0, "inner", 2);
   add_vertex(1, "outer", 3);
   add_vertex(2, "other");
   ```

All the above options **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8cb27249c4f5bdd)**

The latter interface is far superior anyways, if you ask me.

If you want you can use ADL to make it available to others:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0ed9033dbb8e5a4)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>

namespace MyLib { // for ADL demo
    struct custom_node {
        custom_node(std::string name, int capacity)
            : name(std::move(name)), capacity(capacity) {}

        std::string name = "uninitialized";
        int capacity = -1;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, custom_node const& cn) {
            return os << "{" << std::quoted(cn.name) << ", " << cn.capacity << "}";
        }
    };

    struct VertexProperties {
        int id{};
        std::unique_ptr<custom_node> node;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, VertexProperties const& vp) {
            os << vp.id;
            if (vp.node)
                os << ", " << *vp.node;
            return os;
        }
    };

    template <typename G>
    auto add_vertex(G& g, int id, const std::string& name, int capacity = -1) {
        auto vd = boost::add_vertex(g);
        g[vd] = { id, std::make_unique<custom_node>(name, capacity) };
        return vd;
    }
}

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, MyLib::VertexProperties>;
using custom_vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using custom_edge = Graph::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    Graph g;

    add_vertex(g, 10, "inner", 2);
    add_vertex(g, 11, "outer", 3);
    add_vertex(g, 12, "other");

    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        std::cout << g[vd] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
10, {"inner", 2}
11, {"outer", 3}
12, {"other", -1}
```

### SOMEONE MENTIONED DESIGN?

If all you want is unique ownership with optional/lazy construction, why not:

```
struct VertexProperties {
    int id{};
    std::optional<custom_node> node;
};
```

Or even just

```
struct VertexProperties {
    int id{};
    custom_node node;
};
```

The ownership semantics will be the same, without the costs:

```
Graph g;

add_vertex({10, custom_node{"inner", 2}}, g);
add_vertex({11, custom_node{"outer", 3}}, g);
add_vertex({12, custom_node{"other"}}, g);
```

That's just using the standard `boost::add_vertex` overloads from BGL. Without `optional<>` it can become even simpler:

```
add_vertex({10, {"inner", 2}}, g);
add_vertex({11, {"outer", 3}}, g);
add_vertex({12, {"other"}}, g);
```

Also **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f3de2f1586f223)** (without std::optional: [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d4288eba13f6bdd))

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

struct custom_node {
    custom_node(std::string name, int capacity = -1)
        : name(std::move(name)), capacity(capacity) {}

    std::string name = "uninitialized";
    int capacity = -1;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, custom_node const& cn) {
        return os << "{" << std::quoted(cn.name) << ", " << cn.capacity << "}";
    }
};

struct VertexProperties {
    int id{};
    std::optional<custom_node> node;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, VertexProperties const& vp) {
        os << vp.id;
        if (vp.node) os << ", " << *vp.node;
        return os;
    }
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperties>;
using custom_vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using custom_edge = Graph::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    Graph g;

    add_vertex({10, custom_node{"inner", 2}}, g);
    add_vertex({11, custom_node{"outer", 3}}, g);
    add_vertex({12, custom_node{"other"}}, g);

    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        std::cout << g[vd] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
10, {"inner", 2}
11, {"outer", 3}
12, {"other", -1}
```

Comment: The point about move-awareness and lack of forwarding answered the question. The provided options are great!
The object that is allocated with the unique_ptr is quite large. My graph will grow over time and so the `m_vertices` vector will be resized. I want to avoid expensive copying there. Maybe I should have clarified, rather a performance than design issue. Your design recommendations are not really applicable to my case.